# Why doesn't this Bash script error out?

Tags: bash

Here's my Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ == "" ]; then
  echo "BAD"
  exit 1
fi

echo "OK"
```

And here's the output:

```
./test.sh: line 3: [: ==: unary operator expected
OK
```

The return code is 0.

There's an obvious syntax error at line 3. Rather than raise the syntax error and refuse to run the script, somehow the script just runs and reports the syntax error at *run time*. The `-e` flag hasn't protected me from this - apparently a syntax error in an `if` statement constitutes a false condition rather than a reason to immediately exit the program. BUT, somehow Bash *has* parsed that whole `if ... fi` block, so after ignoring the bad line, execution somehow resumes not at the next syntactically correct line but after the end of the block?

I have two questions:

1. What is going on?
2. How can I protect myself from this behaviour in future?

Comment: **1** `if` runs the command `[`, and just examines its return code. Bash doesn't know nor care about the syntax for the `[` command. (You can put some other command there, and Bash still won't know anything about its syntax.) **2** Use `[[` instead of `[`, and http://www.shellcheck.net .

Comment: @Biffen right, but `[` should be a builtin as well, (at least in my shell, where I can still reproduce the problem)

Comment: On a technical level... yes. But `if` **is** a builtin, it *could* very well handle syntax errors. It just doesn't.

Comment: Despite the fact that `[` and `[[` are builtins in bash, bash maintains behaviour as if it were not, even out of POSIX compatibility mode. Things are "built in" for convenience and speed, not to change the logic of the language.

Comment: Either way, it's _not_ a syntax error.

Comment: … I'm not describing how things *should* be, just answering the question ‘*What is going on?*’. And as others mentioned: Even if it's a builtin, I for one still want it to behave as a standard command.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Right. As indicated the thing that is throwing an error on the bogus syntax is `[` (builtin or not). It is doing that when it gets to that point. (Doing it earlier would be odd. Shell scripts aren't pre-compiled.) Could it happen as part of `if` instead of `[`? ... I guess but that would be extra, very specific, logic in the shell's parser/etc.

Comment: @ghoti That's correct for `[` but not for `[[` since the latter is a bashism, meaning there is no `/bin/[[` which needs to get emulated.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The shell absolutely **does** handle `if`-related syntax errors. Try `if ;then echo foo; fi` or `if then echo foo; fi` for example. (Though I'll grant that those aren't `if` doing anything exactly.) The issue here **isn't** an error with `if` or the command list. It is an error with the `[` command/builtin.

Comment: With `[[` instead of `[` here I get a different error and the script terminates immediately (bash 3.2.25 and 4.1.2).

Comment: Wrong wording, meant `[`.

Comment: Somebody should answer here

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Ok, yeah, the shell could handle `[` syntax errors the way it handles `[[` syntax errors but that gets back to ghoti's comment about speed/etc. versus changing logic and runtime behavior. A script changing behavior depending on whether `[` was builtin or not would be fairly surprising I think.

Comment: @EtanReisner is that not because it only has one side of the argument ?

Comment: @123 Is what because of that?

Comment: @EtanReisner Nvm Just read all the comments.

Comment: @123 Yes. My point was that the error you get with `[[` (which is a bash *language* construct) is different then the error you get with the `[` command/builtin.

Comment: @Biffen should post the answer here, as first commenter. :)

Comment: @EtanReisner: yes I've already read that comment.

Answer (score 15):

1. `if` runs the command [`[`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test), and just examines its return code. Bash doesn't know nor care about the syntax for the `[` command.

   You can put some other command there, and Bash still won't know anything about its particular syntax.
2. Two things come to mind:

   - Using [`[[`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005d_005d) instead of `[`: Bash *does* know and care about *its* syntax.
   - Using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)<sup>1</sup>; online, manually or within your favourite editor.

Both `if` and `-e` deal with exit codes: If it's non-zero `if` won't let you into the `then` block, and `-e` will exit. You can't really have both those behaviours at once. (Well, it *seems* `[` exits with different codes for false results (1) and syntax errors (2), so it might be *possible* to ‘detect’ syntax errors.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Or some other tool, but that's the only one of which I know. Suggestions welcome.</sup>

Comment: @qntm It's an alternative form of the [`test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command.

Comment: I'm flabberghasted. Any other non-alphanumeric commands I should know about? Is `;` a special command too? How about `"`? At this stage I would believe anything.

Comment: @qntm no, but `:` and `.` are builtin commands as well (although - unlike `[` - POSIX defines these as special)

Comment: @qntm Some punctuation characters have special meanings to the shell. `;` and `"` do. You absolutely _could_ make a `/usr/bin/;`, but to invoke it, you would have to escape the `;`, so it's probably not going to catch on. `[` just happens to not have any special meaning, leaving it fair-game for whoever decided that `if [ $condition ]` reads better than `if test $condition`.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have a shell syntax error here.

You have an error in the arguments to the `[` command/builtin.

The reason `set -e` doesn't help here is because that's **explicitly** not what it is supposed to do. `set -e` would become **entirely** useless if you couldn't have `if` statements in your code with it on. Just think about that.

If you look in the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) for what the `-e`/`errexit` flag does you see this description:

> **-e**
>
> When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the reasons listed in [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) or by returning an exit status greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit with the following exceptions:
>
> 1. The failure of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit. Only the failure of the pipeline itself shall be considered.
> 2. The **-e** setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the **while**, **until**, **if**, or **elif** reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the **!** reserved word, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last.
> 3. If the exit status of a compound command other than a subshell command was the result of a failure while -e was being ignored, then -e shall not apply to this command.
>
> This requirement applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately. For example, in:
>
> ```
> set -e; (false; echo one) | cat; echo two
> ```

See point two there? That's your situation.

The reason the shell continues to execute is back to the "not a shell syntax error". You have a command error. The `[` command/builtin attempted to parse its arguments and failed. It then returned an error return code. The `if` caught that, skipped its body and returned true (as per documented behavior of `if` when no conditions return true). So the shell script continued normally.

As I indicated in my comment, however, if you had used `[[` (which is a bash-ism and a language construct) then your script *would have* had a syntax error and would have exited immediately on that line (at least in my tests).

Answer (score 2):

From the bash man page

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a subshell command enclosed in parentheses, or one of the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status. The shell **does not exit** if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, **part of the test following the if or elif reserved words**, part of any command executed in a && or ││ list except the command following the final && or ││, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits. This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

First, that isn't a syntax error. You are simply providing bad arguments to the `[` command.

Second, the exit status of a command in the list following the `if` keyword are ignored for the purpose of the `-e` option.